# Symfony2, Doctrine, getDoctrine() without __construct() method

Tags: symfony, service, controller, doctrine

We have service as

```
services:
    service_name:
        class: One\SomeBundle\Controller\OurController
```

What need we add, to make $this->getDoctrine() works in our "OurController" ?
I tried in "OurController"

```
$this->countainer->get('doctrine') 
// and
$this->getDoctrine()
```

but nothing happens, just errors.

I want that this controller use native methods such as $this->getDoctrine(). As I know we can give arguments to controller(arguments in services.yml), and then apply it, but can we set it as default? Without

```
function __construct($em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

and other additional stuff. All i need is to make $this->getDocrine() works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the doctrine is avaiable in all controllers like this

`$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();`

if you want the doctrine available in your service then use something like this

```
services:
    your.service:
        class: YourVendor\YourBundle\Service\YourService
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

Comment: i understood that there no solution, so to give EM by argument best way out

Answer (score 0):

When you define a service, you have to pass parameters as arguments as follow (since a service doesn't have access to the main container by default):

```
<services>
    <service id="myservice" class="path/to/my/class">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine" />
        ...
    </service>
</services>
```

This is configured in xml but I'll let you convert it in yml if you like.

Then in your service class you just need to set your constructor as so:

```
class MyServiceClass
{
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine $doctrine, ...)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        ....
    }
}
```

Now the doctrine service will be available in your own service Class.

Comment: i wrote in question, without __construct method, i know how to do it with arguments

Answer (score 0):

And your can usage JMSDiExtra for set services to properties in Controller:

Controller code:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

/**
 * Controller class
 */
class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @DI\Inject
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @DI\Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager")
     */
    protected $em;

    // .....

    /**
     * Action
     */
    public function myAction()
    {
        // ....
        $this->em->persist($myObject);
        // ....
    }
}
```

More documentation with JMSDiExtra - http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle

This bundle is a default in Symfony2 Framework